# What is the correct casing of mapping in vim?

Tags: vim, mapping, casing

I'm confused with these mappings:

```
map <c-c>
map <C-C>
map <c-C>
map <C-c>
```

Are they different ? Which is the correct way to write this mapping ?

Same question with:

```
map <s-Tab>
map <S-TAB>
map <s-tab>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<C-c>`, `<c-c>`, `<c-C>` and `<C-C>` are strictly equivalent but…

1. Read `:help key-notation`.
2. Always use the notation you see in the first column.
3. ?
4. Profit.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the case doesn't matter. When you define

```
:map <c-c> foo
```

and then list via

```
:map <c-c>
<C-C>   foo
```

it shows the uppercase version. So, the modifiers (`C` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, etc.) are case-insensitive. For the keys, you usually use the `S` modifier (as in `<C-S-c>`) for shifted keys; however, as a special case, for the `<A-...>` keys, the uppercase key is different from the lowercase one, i.e. `<A-S-c>` == `<A-C>`.

I recommend to adhere to the format used at `:help key-notation`.